# How to Print method call in php?

Tags: php, soap, soap-client

I am try to using Alison APi on my website by using the **nusoap-0.9.5** now this is the api code  i have i and password please help me how i can add this API and i want to print this in PHP.

```
<?php

 include "nusoap.php";

$alisonOrgId = '';
$alisonOrgKey = '';

$client = new nusoap_client("https://alison.com/api/service.php?wsdl");


$headers = '
<SOAP-ENV:Header>
<ns2:credentials>
    <alisonOrgId>'.$alisonOrgId.'</alisonOrgId>
    <alisonOrgKey>'.$alisonOrgKey.'</alisonOrgKey>
</ns2:credentials>
</SOAP-ENV:Header>
';

$client->setHeaders($headers);
$client->decode_utf8 = false;

$result = $client->call('getAvailableCourses');

while ($row= $result->fetch_accos()) {
echo $row['category'];
}

// Display $result

?>
```

and this is the renaming file and lib 
http://sourceforge.net/projects/nusoap/

i have try many type to print

```
print_r($result);
```

Now i want to use it as the value print into the tables.

Comment: You can use echo in php like.. _<td><?= $result['field1'] ?></td>_ etc.

Comment: i don't know that how many fields are there.

Comment: then just $result... use some var_dump to check content of variable